# User Portal for Specific Clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, keystonejs

I need some back end assistance here.

We're building a portal and upon login the user will be navigated to the appropriate landing page where they may find certain files they have subscribed for.

We've been looking at React, Node, Mongo, and Keystone to build this out.

I'm curious to see how one would be able to manually add users and passwords in keystone that would allow them to login initially and be directed to an appropriate landing page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you could manage this in the state of your application. I can't speak on Keystone but think of it like this.

Keystone has your auth information for users which is tied to a users document in your mongo database. Once a user is logged in / auth'd you can pull the user data in via an api request and then route based on the response at the app level.

We do this currently with redux, react, and a postgres database to route users to pages based on the company they are assigned to.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the user in your model, then you need to implement a custom login page, not the one that keystone provides by default since that automatically will redirect to you to the admin panel.

I think a way of achieve this is implement a custom login page, then in your controller, if the login is successful you can redirect that user to a route defined in the user model.